# laravel Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the babel package to the babel-cli package

Tags: php, laravel-5, npm

I had this error in laravel executing Gulp command: "Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the babel package to the babel-cli package".

I was updating to laravel 5.3 doing again all the gulp stuff to compile css/js...

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to update npm with this command:
    sudo npm install npm -g
then 
    sudo rm -rf node_modules
    sudo ppm install
and at last again
    sudo gulp